# ng-switch to change user interface of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-switch

I've created a directive for showing a person details:

```
angular.module('person.directives', []).
directive("person", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "person/views/person.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        myPerson: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    }        
}
```

});

the view:

```
<div>
<span>FirstName: {{myPerson.firstName}}</span><span>LastName: {{myPerson.lastName}}               </span>
 </div>
```

The way it's called:

```
<person my-person="mandat.Person"></person>
```

mandat being a property of the parent controller.

Now, if myPerson is null, the UI for the directive should show a search button instead of the person details.

What's the best way for doig that ? Can I use the ng-switch statement ? How would I use it in this particular case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out... I use ng-show and ng-hide

```
<div>
<div ng-show="myPerson">
    <span>FirstName: {{myPerson.firstName}}</span><span>LastName: {{myPerson.lastName}}</span>
</div>
<div ng-hide="myPerson">
    <button>search</button>

</div>
```